# circle drawing algorithm for n-pixel border

Tags: graphics

I know the Bresenham and related algorithms, and I found a good algorithm to draw a circle with a 1-pixel wide border. Is there any 'standard' algorithm to draw a circle with an n-pixel wide border, without restoring to drawing n circles?

Drawing the pixel and n<sup>2</sup> surrounding pixels might be a solution, but it draws many more pixels than needed.

I am writing a graphics library for an embedded system, so I am not looking for a way to do this using an existing library, although a library that does this function and is open source might be a lead.

Comment: I know it was a long time ago but do you remember the approach you ended up taking? I find myself in the same situation in an embedded system.

Comment: Was it that long agao?? I never found a solution that was good enough for my taste...

Answer (score 1):

Compute the points for a single octant for both radii at the same time and simultaneously replicate it eight ways, which is how Bresenham circles are usually drawn anyway. To avoid overdrawing (e.g., for XOR drawing), the second octant should be constrained to draw outside the first octant's x-extents.

Note that this approach breaks down if the line is very thick compared to the radius.

Comment: Did you ever try this? For small widths it results in a very ugly circle. For instance for width 2 the circle will sometimes be 2 but sometimes 1 pixel width.

Comment: A width of two is too small to yield good results. You need to use widths of at least three, ideally four or five. For very small thicknesses, you might be better off drawing a single radius and stretching the pixels to the desired width (vertically for the north/south octants and horizontally for east/west). Failing that, antialiasing is really the only way to achieve good results.

Comment: I did try the stretching approach, but the result was awfull. Do you know any code that does the strteching and/or anti-aliasing? (is anti-aliasing possibe with 1-bit b/w??)

Comment: Antialiasing can be achieved by using the Bresenham algorithm's accumulator to set the intensity of the edge pixels, but I'm afraid this doesn't help with 1-bit pixels. The only other thing I can suggest — as an experiment — is to draw a large filled white circle, then a small filled black circle inside it and see how that comes out. If that looks OK, then think of ways to draw exactly the same pixels without filling (or maybe the double fill is an acceptable solution).

Comment: No, double fill is not acceptable for performance reasons. I have cconsidered that circle-within-circle approach, but it is quite complex and does not work well for very small (1 or 2 pixel) borders.

Answer (score 1):

Treat it as a rasterization problem:

Take the bounding box of your annulus.
Consider the image rows falling in the bounding box.
For each row, compute the intersection with the 2 circles (ie solve x^2+y^2=r^2, so x=sqrt(r^2-y^2) for each, for x,y relative to the circle centres.
Fill in the spans.  Repeat for next row.

This approach generalizes to all sorts of shapes, can produce sub-pixel coordinates useful for anti-aliasing and scales better with increasing resolution than hacky solutions involving multiple shifted draws.

If the sqrt looks scary for an embedded system, bear in mind there are fast approximate algorithms which would probably be good enough, especially if you're rounding off to the nearest pixel.